# Show inequality about the arithmetic mean of logits

Tags: inequality

I want to show that for some integers with $0 < n_1 < m_1 < n_2 < m_2 < N$ and $n_2-n_1 \leq m_2-m_1$ that

$\frac{1}{n_2-n_1+1}\sum\limits_{j=n_1}^{n_2} logit \left(\frac{j}{N}\right) \leq \frac{1}{m_2-m_1+1}\sum\limits_{j=m_1}^{m_2} logit \left(\frac{j}{N}\right)$

with $logit(x)=log(x/1-x)$.

Since logit is a monotone function the right hand side is the mean of a larger (or equally large) set of larger numbers than the left hand side and intuitively the inequality must be true.

I tried to prove it by splitting the sums into two parts (the left from $n_1$ to $m_1-1$ and from $m_1$ to $n_2$ and the right from $m_1$ to $n_2$ and from $n_2+1$ to $m_2$). But I always get stuck at some point (the sums could be negative). I also tried a proof by induction on $n_1$ and $n_2$, unsuccessfully. I would really appreciate any hints on how to prove this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $n_1\le j\le m_2$ put $a_j=\operatorname{logit}\frac jN$. Then a sequence $\{a_j\}$ is increasing. We have to show that

$$(m_2-m_1+1)(a_{n_1}+\dots+a_{n_2})\leq (n_2-n_1+1)(a_{m_1}+\dots+a_{m_2}).$$

Since $a_{n_1}+\dots+a_{n_1+m_2-m_1}\le  a_{m_1}+\dots+a_{m_2}$, it suffices to show that

$$(m_2-m_1+1)(a_{n_1}+\dots+a_{n_2})\leq (n_2-n_1+1)(a_{n_1}+\dots+a_{n_1+m_2-m_1})$$

or that

$$(m_2-m_1-n_2+n_1)(a_{n_1}+\dots+a_{n_2})\leq (n_2-n_1+1)(a_{n_2+1}+\dots+a_{n_1+m_2-m_1}).$$

The last inequality holds because $$a_{n_1}+\dots+a_{n_2}\le (n_2-n_1+1)a_{n_2}$$ and
$$(n_1+m_2-m_1-n_2)a_{n_2}\le a_{n_2+1}+\dots+a_{n_1+m_2-m_1}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just don't see that ${a_j}$ is a sequence of positive numbers because logit(j/N) is negative for $j<N/2$. Is that relevant for the next steps?

Comment: @cragcrawl Oops, right. Corrected. Fortunately, this is not relevant for the next steps.